# second order nonlinear DE

Tags: matlab, ode, nonlinear-equation

I am trying to solve a second-order nonlinear differential equation. The result shows there is no solution but when I check with WolframAlpha there exists a solution. I used this code and there is no solution. I want to know that if the code has a problem or Matlab can not solve it. Thank you.

```
syms z(t) t A B C D
zp = diff(z,t);
zpp = diff(z,t,2);
eqn = ( A*zpp  + B*z^2 + C*z == D );
cond = [z(0)==0, zp(0)==0];
zSol = dsolve(eqn,cond,'IgnoreAnalyticConstraints',true);
zSol = unique(simplify(zSol))
```

Comment: Did you test your code by removing B? Basically set B=0, which means remove all B containing terms from the code, and then check if Matlab is going to solve the equation. If it does, the syntax is ok but Matlab doesn't know how to solve the original equation (because its solution includes inversions of elliptic integrals, e.i. elliptic functions).

Answer (score 0):

If by solution you mean a solution in terms of elementary functions, there is no such solution. There is a solution in terms of elliptic functions. I suspect, that's the reason for the difference between Matlab and WolframAlpha. Wolfram probably includes elliptic functions and manages to display them. Maybe Matlab doesn't do that. Either way, you can solve the equation up to the point where time t is equal to an elliptic integral, which, in order to invert, you need the aforementioned elliptic function.